# Distribution of random Fourier coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, fourier-analysis

Let $f : \{0, 1\}^{n} \rightarrow \{-1, 1\}$ be a Boolean function. Let the Fourier coefficients of this function be given by

$$ \hat f(z) = \frac{1}{2^{n}} \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}} f(x)(-1)^{x \cdot z}$$

for each $z \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$, where $x \cdot z$ is the bitwise inner product between $x$ and $z$. Let me choose a function uniformly at random from the set of all Boolean functions $$\{f : \{0, 1\}^{n} \rightarrow \{-1, 1\}\}. $$

What is the distribution that the square of each Fourier coefficient $\hat f(z)^{2}$ is distributed as?

Answer (score 0):

$\hat{f}(z)$ is $\frac{1}{2^n}$ times the sum of $2^n$ iid Bernoulli random variables taking on the values $1, -1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each, for every $z$ (the signs $(-1)^{x \cdot z}$ don't affect this!). So it has a binomial distribution: we have

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \hat{f}(z) = \frac{2^n - 2k}{2^n} \right) = \frac{1}{2^{2^n}} {2^n \choose k}.$$

So the square is distributed as the square of this binomial distribution; I don't know if it has a name but its properties are deducible from the properties of a binomial distribution. In particular its mean is the variance of $\hat{f}(z)$, which is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. As a sanity check, Parseval's theorem gives

$$\| f \|^2 = 1 = \| \hat{f} \| = \sum_{z \in \{ 0, 1 \}^n} \hat{f}(z)^2$$

so if $\mathbb{E}(\hat{f}(z)^2)$ is independent of $z$ it must be equal to $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Is the square of the binomial distribution distributed over a probability simplex? How to check this?

Comment: @RandomMatrices: I don't know what you mean by "distributed over a probability simplex."

Comment: As in, I could not understand how we are ensuring $\sum_{z} \hat f(z)^{2} = 1$. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Also, since there are $2^{n}$ trials, shouldn't it be $\mathbb{P} \left( \hat{f}(z) = \frac{n-2k}{2^n} \right) = \frac{1}{2^{2^n}} {2^{n} \choose k}$?

Comment: @RandomMatrices: yep, sorry, I fixed it. Also for the first result I think I am missing a normalization constant so I'll have to fix that too. It should follow from Parseval's theorem as I said (with appropriate normalizations): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem

Comment: Ha, yep, I messed up both the variance calculation and Parseval's theorem in the same direction so my sanity check didn't work, whoops.